# Android, Text / Font renders as Squares

Tags: android, text, opengl-es, fonts, share

When I try sharing an image through my program, the share menu sometimes comes out looking like this.

Some Notes:

1) It doesn't seem to occur on the first run, but only after I have paused the application and gone back in.

2) My app uses OpenGL extensively. It is possible I am changing a shared setting, then not returning the value back to the original.

3) Everything else in my application works fine.

4) I have tried removing all the calls that allow transparencies, and I am still having this problem.

[image]

Comment: I also have this problem and it sounds like my situation is similar to yours: It doesn't happen on the first run either. I also make extensive use of the hardware rendering and my interface has several semi-transparent graphics layers on top of each other.

I have 2 thoughts on this:
- I might try and disable hardware rendering (place a toggle so users can disable hardware rendering)
- This looks like a memory problem (font is unloaded from memory), but I don't find any related exceptions thrown in the log.

Comment: are you using fonts of any other language than english??

Comment: I am using Dutch as a language (enforced localization), but no custom fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this problem too. I am using a GLES 2.0 context, the only way I have been able to get rid of this... (it's going to sound weird) is by NOT calling

GLES20.glDeleteTextures ( hTextures.length, hTextures, 0 );

It wasn't happening before I started clearing up my textures, and it hasn't happened again since removing it. I have no idea why that would be though?

I'm also not sure of the ramifications of not releasing my textures.

If anyone can shed light on the matter, that'd be great, there's a few versions of questions floating around. Appears it's a problem in Unity for android and everything.

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes this problem, and not happens ever, just randomly.

I have cleaned my project and uninstall from device, compile and install again, to me works fine.

Hope this helps.